# How can I get a new array from the second item onwards in c#?

Tags: c#, algorithm, arrays

I originally had this code which I mistakenly thought would do what I wanted it to:

```
string firstArg = args[0];
string[] otherArgs = args.Except(new string[] { args[0] }).ToArray();
```

However, it seems that the .Except method removes duplicates.  So if I was to pass through the arguments `a b c c`, the result of `otherArgs` would be `b c` not `b c c`.

So how can I get a new array with all the elements from the second element onwards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`Skip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358985.aspx) method:

```
var otherArgs = args.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for that - first thing I stumbled across after posting this question!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have a desination array in mind:

```
string[] otherArgs = args.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

If you do:

```
Array.Copy(args, 1, otherArgs, 0, args.Length - 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using linq as it appears you are and from the top of my head:

```
string[] otherArgs = args.skip(1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the [ConstrainedCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.constrainedcopy.aspx) method.  Here's some example code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string firstArg = args[0];
    Array otherArgs = new string[args.Length - 1];
    Array.ConstrainedCopy(args, 1, otherArgs, 0, args.Length - 1);

    foreach (string foo in otherArgs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(foo);
    }
}
```

}